# In AngularJS, how to use a parameter in a filter filter function?

Tags: angularjs, function, ionic-framework, filter, parameters

```
<div ng-repeat="city in cities">
  <div>city: {{city}}</div>

  <div ng-repeat="contact in contacts | filter:selectItems(city)">
    contact: {{contact.name}}
  </div>

  <hr>
</div>


angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.selectItems = function (item, city) {
      return item.city === city;
    };
  });
```

It doesn't work. Because there is a parameter **city** in the filter filter function. But in such occasions, what's the correct syntax to use a parameter in the filter filter function? Or does a parameter is allowed in the filter filter function?

Comment: What is item in the $scope.selectItems = function (item, city) {} You have not passed item where you called it.

Comment: I thought the first parameter (item) was passed to the function automatically, so I just need to manually pass the second parameter.

Comment: This is a good resource: https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-custom-angularjs-filters

Comment: Thank you for the tutorials of custom filters. But I can't use a custom filter after a ng-repeat directive, and can only use a filter filter there. Their names are confusingly similar, but they are two different kinds of filters.@WilliamHampshire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using custom filter

```
yourmodule.filter('selectItems', function () {
  return function (items, city) {
    //your logic
  };
});


<div ng-repeat="contact in contacts | selectItems:city">
    contact: {{contact.name}}
  </div>
```

Some other reference which have the same scenario of you
http://plnkr.co/edit/vtNjEgmpItqxX5fdwtPi?p=preview

Comment: Thank you! It seems a good solution! But it seems not work too. Because I can only use a filter filter after a ng-repeat directive, and can't use a custom filter, which can only be used after a certain data.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reference you find me on plnkr.co! Yes, it's right the same scenario of mine. And it perfectly solves my problem! Thank you very much! @JEMI